# validating inline_formsets when the main form doesn't validate

Tags: django, django-validation

I have an estimate for which has a collection of details about a potential client. Things like name, address, etc. Easy stuff. I then have a few `inlineformset`s for products, labour, etc. that are tied to the main estimate.

The problem I'm having is a bit of a catch 22. My thoughts were that I would do the validation in this manner:

1. Run `mainForm.is_valid()`
2. If the main form validates, then save it and move to the 'sub' forms (`inlineformset`s)
3. Run `my_inlineformset.is_valid()`
4. If the `my_inlineformset` validates, then save it too - and 'attach' it to the `mainForm` by the `mainForm`'s ID.

Here's the catch:
If the main form doesn't validate, then it doesn't save. If it doesn't save, I have nothing to 'attach' the `inlineformset` to. Thus, when the `mainForm` doesn't validate and I'm kicked back to the form to fix the errors, the `inlineformset` will be blank. So if the user fills out a bunch of stuff on the `inlineformset` but screws up the `mainForm` then when they're kicked back to the form to fix their errors, all their data on the `inlineformset` is gone.

I tried to circumvent this issue by first saving the `inlineformset` and only attaching it to the main form after the main form validates. The problem with this is that I could be saving a bunch of `inlineformset`s for nothing -- they'll never be attached to an estimate. I don't want a whole wack of records that aren't attached to anything and, essentially, will just float around in the database unecessarily.

Here's my view code:

```
    if main.is_valid():
        tmp = main.save(commit=False)
        if estID != 'new':
            tmp.routeNum = est.routeNum
            tmp.estMap = est.estMap
            tmp.estSketch = est.estSketch
        if estID == 'new':
            tmp.proposalID = newEstID('R')
            tmp.sysType = 'R'
        if estID == 'new':
            pform = pFormSet(request.POST, instance=tmp, prefix="product_form")
            lform = lFormSet(request.POST, instance=tmp, prefix="labour_form")
            oform = oFormSet(request.POST, instance=tmp, prefix="other_form")
        else:
            pform = pFormSet(request.POST, instance=est, prefix="product_form")
            lform = lFormSet(request.POST, instance=est, prefix="labour_form")
            oform = oFormSet(request.POST, instance=est, prefix="other_form")

        if pform.is_valid():
            pform.save()
```

So you can see that if main doesn't validate, then my `FormSet`s will never be checked for validation (and then it throws an error that `pform` called before initiated). However, if I validate `pform` before main, then how do I 'attach' `pform` to `main` if `main` itself doesn't validate (and thus doesn't save)?

So how does one hang on to the inline formset data and if another form on the same page doesn't validate?

---

**EDIT**

I'm wondering about just splitting this page (which has 4 forms -- a main form and 3 inline forms) into 4 steps. The user must fill out each form seperately. That way I can validate safely without worry about the issues I'm mentioning above. Of course, this seems like I'm making the user do more work than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you need to validate and save your main form before you instantiate the formsets. The usual thing to do is to instantiate all the forms first, then validate them all before saving anything. That way you can guarantee that the forms will only be saved if they all validate, and if any of them fail you'll simply redisplay everything with the relevant errors.

Comment: Ya, you nailed it. For whatever reason I had it in my mind that I needed to save the main form first, then validate/save the formsets. I just did what you mention and not I think it's working as it should be. The non-validating main form doesn't affect the sub forms, and they keep all their data even if they (or the main form) haven't been saved.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is ok, showing all this forms on one page, but maybe you don't need formsets? .. I'm not completely sure, but if you just need 1 instance of each form in the page, maybe you don't need formsets at all.

About the validation, just handle 3 different forms, and then on the save process, do all the save-management manually and before saving the main form (commit=False) you assign the multiple relationships.

Assuming M is for the main-model and A, B for the related models for which M has foreign keys to, then you could do it like this:

```
# views.py ...

def my_display_forms_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        m = M()
        a = A()
        b = B()

        a_form = AForm(request.POST, instance=a)
        b_form = BForm(request.POST, instance=b)
        m_form = MForm(request.POST, instance=m)

        if a_form.is_valid() and b_form.is_valid() and m_form.is_valid():
            a = a_form.save()
            b = b_form.save()
            m = m_form.save(commit=False); # don't save it to db still
            m.a = na
            m.b = nb
            m.save()
            # eventually do some more stuff
    else:
       # generate new unbound forms here
       a_form = AForm()
       b_form = BForm()
       m_form = MForm()
    return render_to_response('template.html', {'m_form': m_form, 'a_form': a_form, 'b_form': b_form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And then on your template:

```
{% if m_form and a_form and b_form %}
<form ... >
<!-- show main form here -->
<fieldset>
<!-- here the other forms -->
</fieldset>
</form>
{% endif %}
```

And that should be it.

Comment: The formsets are necessary because the user should be able to add multiple products -- so multiple forms of products. Hence, the formsets. Likewise for the labour and "other" formsets I have.